# How to fetch data from servlet and dynamically show as checkboxes in jquery dialogue box

Tags: jquery, servlets, checkbox, jquery-dialog

I have a jquery dialogue box where i am displaying checkboxes and it is hardcoded.currently number of checkboxes displayed is fixed as present in hardcoded data.Now i got a requirement where i need to show these checkboxes dynamically from data achieved from server side using servlet in java but i have no idea as how to retrieve data from servlet and display it into dialogue box as checkbox dynamically.

The dialogue box is opening on clicking a link button..

here is my code containing hardcoded checkboxes and dilaogue box along with link button click event..

```
var $calltype = $('<div></div>')
        .html('<form id="calltype" action=""><input type="checkbox" id="LOCAL" name="LOCAL" value="LOCAL" />LOCAL<br /><input type="checkbox" name="STD"  id="STD" value="STD" /> STD <br /><input type="checkbox" name="ISD" id="ISD" value="ISD" />ISD<br /><input type="checkbox" name="INCOMING" id="INCOMING" value="INCOMING" />INCOMING<br /><input type="checkbox" name="INET" id="INET" value="INET" />INET<br /></form>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Select Calltype',
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function() {  $('form#calltype').submit();},
                "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
            }
        });

        $('#callltype').click(function(evt) {
            selcalltype="";
            $calltype.dialog('open');
            evt.preventDefault();
            // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
            return false;
        });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically so you can not bind events directly.You have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('click','#calltype',function(evt) {
     selcalltype="";
     $calltype.dialog('open');
     evt.preventDefault();
     // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
     return false;
});
```

and your `id` is `calltype` not `callltype` extra `l`

**Syntax**

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for **event delegation** like,

```
$(document).on('click','#calltype',function(evt) {
     selcalltype="";
     $calltype.dialog('open');
     evt.preventDefault();
     // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
     return false;
});
```

Also you used **$('#callltype')** but it should be **$('#calltype')**, if you `change the id` then your code **also works**